# Azure data factory encoding issue for characters with acute. For example: ú, á, é

Tags: character-encoding, azure-data-factory

Azure data factory is not encoding the special characters properly.

For example, the CSV file has word **sún** which gets converted into **sÃºn** after performing transformation through data flow and writing it to the blob storage container.

There are many files with different encoding types in my container which dataflow is selecting to apply transformation and these encoding types are like UTF-8, ANSI, etc.

So if I set my encoding part to WINDOWS-1252 in DelimitedText dataset then it works fine for ANSI encoding type csv file but if encoding type if UTF-8 then I have to set this part to UTF-8, then only dataflow generates proper output for these special characters.
[Dataset Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul80n.png)

My CSV file data screenshot is here: [CSV file data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1ARu.png)

Is there any generic way that irrespective of what encoding type of file, we can generate proper output for such characters?

Comment: I tested in Copy active and data flow, it all works with UTF-8 encoding in Source and Sink. The `sún` wasn't converted to `sÃºn`. Every thing works well. Did you check the data preview?

Comment: @LeonYue , Thank for you reply. I am not using copy activity. But if we talk about data flow then can you please let me know details for below question.
**1.** Did you try with CSV file ?
**2.** If CSV file then what was the encoding type of your csv file, UTF-8 or ANSI ?
**3.** For dataflow which dataset you used? DelimitedText csv ?
**4.** If DelimitedText dataset then what was the encoding type you used in that ? Default UTF-8 or something else ?

Comment: off course I use csv the file with data contains 'sún', reading the csv data with UTF-8 encoding. Data flow also use csv file (derived text) same with Copy active. If you need I could post screenshots as answer then you can accept(mark) it .

Comment: Can you show us piece of your csv data?

Comment: @LeonYue , now can you please try one thing by keeping everything as it is and convert the encoding type of your CSV file to ANSI and try the same procedure? So I think now when you will try to read this ANSI formatted file with UTF encoding, it will misbehave for special characters. And I want a generic way with which any encoding type can be tackled. Thanks.

Comment: @LeonYue , here is the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1ARu.png) of CSV sample data.

Comment: Hi @Ankit Chhelavda, I got it if I understand you correctly. For Data Factory, we must choose one encoding type firstly to read the file. If you files have many encoding, you want to keep the data between different encoding, that is limited my the encoding type not Data Factory. If the output encoding can't parse the data and it will be converted to other type. Data Factory only provide these encoding type for us to read/write data.

Comment: Alright got it, thanks. Is there any way in data-factory with which I can read the encoding type (UTF-8 or ANSI) of the file which data-flow trying to read so based on that I will apply encoding in the dataset dynamically?

Comment: I'm afraid no, data factory can't do that, it can't get the encoding type of the files. Maybe you can achieve that in code level, try function or notebook. I will post it. If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Ankit Chhelavda, do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it if I understand you correctly. For Data Factory, we must choose one encoding type firstly to read the file. If you files have many encoding, you want to keep the data between different encoding, that is limited my the encoding type not Data Factory. If the output encoding can't parse the data and it will be converted to other type. Data Factory only provide these encoding type for us to read/write data.

Data Factory can't get the encoding type of the files even with get Metadata active. Maybe you can achieve that in code level, try function or notebook, that's the only way.

HTH.